# Оператор сравнения на равенство в реализации шаблонных классов С++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, шаблоны-с++

Где-то уже даже и не помню упоминалось, что лучше делать перегрузку сравнение оператора `==` для шаблонных классов, с помощью следующего действия:

```
bool operator == (l, r) {
  return !(l > r || r > l);
}
```

*Как с точки логики в реализации это может быть полезно?*

Comment: Ну, тогда можно обойтись единственным отношением "меньше" для чего угодно...

Comment: Этот прием гарантирует, что `==` и  `<` согласованы между собой.

Comment: @Chorkov.      Не понял предложения, можно подробней?

Comment: @Harry, так вроде stl такое сравнение на равенство и использует?

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну да, он принимает одно "меньше"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это не самое хорошее решение.

В общем случае `==` `!=` могут быть быстрее, чем `<` `<=` `>` `>=`. Например, для `std::string`, `==` `!=` могут сначала сравнить размер, и не проверять содержимое строки, если размер разный. А `<` и остальные операторы так сделать не могут.

Так что не получится нормально реализовать все через один оператор (`<` или даже `<=>`), нужно как минимум два осмысленных оператора: в C++20 это `==` и `<=>` (остальные сгенерируются сами), а до C++20 это `==` и `<`  (`!=` реализовать через `==`, остальные четыре через `<`).

Если даже два оператора писать неохота, а сравнение нужно лексикографическое по списку полей, то сделать функцию а-ля `auto tie() const {return std::tie(a, b, c);}`, а дальше реализовывать операторы в духе `friend bool operator==(const A &x, const A &y) {return a.tie() == b.tie();}`.